# Can I use Dailymotion sdk on swift

Tags: ios, swift, dailymotion-api

I want to use https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-player-sdk-ios
and this is the demo app on objective-c https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-api-demo-objc
Can I implement it in swift?

Comment: you already have a demo app in swift with the sdk

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need a bridging header. Consult Apple's documentation for getting this setup:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: how to implement this on swift ?! no one used it on swift, relay!?